# How can I get the middle part of a file name which have a separator?

Tags: bash, shell

I know the methods of get the first and last part of a file name which is separated by a delimiter. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
file_name=aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd
first_name=${file_name%%.*}
last_name=${file_name##*.}
echo first name is: $first_name
echo last name is: $last_name
```

The output is:

```
first name is: aaa
last name is: ddd
```

But if I want to get `bbb` or `ccc`, how can I get it? Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ file_name=aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd
$ echo "$file_name" | awk -F. '{print $2}'
bbb
$ echo "$file_name" | awk -F. '{print $3}'
ccc
```

Or, to capture in variables:

```
$ middle1=$(echo "$file_name" | awk -F. '{print $2}')
$ middle2=$(echo "$file_name" | awk -F. '{print $3}')
$ echo "middle1=$middle1 and middle2=$middle2"
middle1=bbb and middle2=ccc
```

#### How it works

- `-F.`

  This tells `awk` to use the period (`.`) as the field separator.  Thus, in awk terminology, the first name will be `$1`, the second `$2`, etc.  The last name in your example is `$4` but, in general, the last name can be accessed as `$NF`.
- `print $2`

  This asks awk to print `$2`, the second name, or whatever name you choose.

Answer (score 1):

Change the [internal field separator](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html):

```
IFS=. read first_name middle1 middle2 last_name <<< "$file_name"
```

The output would look like this:

```
echo $first_name
aaa
echo $middle1
bbb
echo $middle2
ccc
echo $last_name
ddd
```

Or with set, also very simple:

```
IFS=. set $file_name
echo $1
aaa
echo $2
bbb
echo $3
ccc
echo $4
ddd
```